# Row Count of various files with in a For Each Loop Container

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container, dataflowtask

I have a Row Count transformation in Data Flow Task and this Data Flow Task is in a For Each Loop Container. So when I am running the package I'm getting the row count for only one file but not all the files.Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Do you want a row count for _each_ file, or a total of all of the row counts for _all_ of the files?

Comment: Total of all rows for all the files.

Comment: You can use an expression task for this purpose i think it is more recommended then using a scrip task since you are just incrementing a variable you don't have any sophisticated logic to implement

Answer (score 3):

## Using an Expression Task

> The Expression Task creates and evaluates expressions that set variable values at runtime, using the Expression Builder

Add 2 variables to your ssis package:

- `@[User::TotalRowCount]`: To store the total count
- `@[User::RowCount]`: To be used in the Row Count transformation

Add an **Expression Task** inside the Foreach Loop container with the following expression:

```
@[User::TotalRowCount] = @[User::TotalRowCount] + @[User::RowCount]
```

**References**

- [SSIS Expression Task](https://chrisalbrektson.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/ssis-expression-task/)
- [Expression Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/expression-task?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Script Task to do this.  Start off by creating another SSIS variable which will store the total count for all iterations of the Foreach Loop.  After this place a Script Task after the Data Flow Task inside the loop.  Add the variable holding the row count for each iteration as a `ReadOnlyVariable` and the variable that will store the total count for all iterations in the `ReadWriteVariables` field.  The following example uses C# to update the value of the total row count variable (`TotalCount`) by adding the count of rows from the variable holding this for the current iteration (`CurrentInterationCount`) to it.

```
int currentRows = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::CurrentInterationCount"].Value.ToString());
int totalRows = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::TotalCount"].Value.ToString());

Dts.Variables["User::TotalCount"].Value = currentRows + totalRows;
```